# Is there anyway to print to a remote client/printer from a cloud-based virtual CentOS machine?

Tags: virtualization, centos, printing, remote, cups

The scenario is that I will potentially be using a cloud based virtual machine and then accessing the machine from a tablet. I then need to send a command to a wireless interfaced printer that will be on the same network as the tablet. So... Tablet asks VM to send print job to printer. Is this possible? I really appreciate the help.